# My Base Adapter, List<Song> songlist has a size of 0, instead of 14. It's preventing me from using my imgCoverArt onClick

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have been trying to create a ListView with the PlaylistsAdapter. But whenever I try to click on imgCoverArt, the app crashes, stating that the songlist has a size of 0. I have tried changing the types of the variables and just changing the codes overall. But I just couldn't fix it and I don't know the issue.

Thanks in advance.

This was the error I got:

```
2020-08-10 03:52:56.720 3091-3091/sg.edu.tp.musicstream E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sg.edu.tp.musicstream, PID: 3091
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at sg.edu.tp.musicstream.PlaylistsAdapter$1.onClick(PlaylistsAdapter.java:88)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have tried to include the relevant classes and please let me know if you need anything else.

```
package sg.edu.tp.musicstream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import sg.edu.tp.musicstream.util.AppUtil;


public class PlaylistsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Song[] songs;
    List<Song> songlist;
    ArrayList<Song> arrayList;

    public PlaylistsAdapter(Context context, List<Song> songlist, Song[] songs)
    {
        mContext = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.songs = songs;
        this.songlist = songlist;
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(songlist);

    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageButton imgCoverArt;
        TextView txtSongTitle;
        TextView txtArtist;
        ImageButton btnAddToPlaylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_listview, null);

            holder.imgCoverArt = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCoverArt);
            holder.txtSongTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSongTitle);
            holder.txtArtist = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtArtist);
            holder.btnAddToPlaylist = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddToPlaylist);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imgCoverArt.setImageResource(songlist.get(position).getCoverArt());
        holder.imgCoverArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int index = 0; index < songs.length; index++)
                {
                    if (songlist.get(position).getId().equals(songs[index].getId())) {
                        Song song = songs[index];
                        sendDataToActivity(songs, song);
                        AppUtil.popMessage(mContext, ""+ songlist.size());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.txtSongTitle.setText(songlist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtArtist.setText(songlist.get(position).getArtist());

        if (position >= 10) {
            holder.btnAddToPlaylist.setContentDescription("S10" + position);
        } else {
            holder.btnAddToPlaylist.setContentDescription("S100" + position);
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    public void sendDataToActivity(Song[] songs, Song song)
    {
        // 1. Create a new Intent and specify the source and destination screen/activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlaySongActivity.class);

        songlist = HomeFragment.arrayList;
        songlist = new ArrayList<>();

        // 2. Store the song information into the Intent object to be sent over to the destination screen.
        intent.putExtra("id", song.getId());
        intent.putExtra("title", song.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("artist", song.getArtist());
        intent.putExtra("fileLink", song.getFileLink());
        intent.putExtra("coverArt", song.getCoverArt());
        intent.putExtra("songs", songs);

        intent.putExtra("songlist", (Serializable) songlist);


        // 3. Launch the destination screen/activity
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        songlist.clear();
        if (charText.length()==0){
            songlist.addAll(arrayList);
        }
        else {
            for (Song song : arrayList){
                if (song.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText) || song.getArtist().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)){
                    songlist.add(song);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

```
package sg.edu.tp.musicstream;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import sg.edu.tp.musicstream.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;
import sg.edu.tp.musicstream.util.AppUtil;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    
    private SongCollection songCollection = new SongCollection();

    static Song[] playlistSongs = new Song[14];

    static ArrayList<Song> playlist = new ArrayList<>();

    private Fragment homeFragment;
    private Fragment playlistsFragment;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        playlistsFragment = new PlaylistsFragment();

        sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setUpViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }


    private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(homeFragment, "Recommended Songs");
        sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(playlistsFragment, "Playlist");
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    public void addToPlaylist (View view) {
        String songId = view.getContentDescription().toString();
        Song song = songCollection.searchById(SongCollection.recommendedSongs, songId);
        playlist.add(song);
        AppUtil.popMessage(this, "Added " + song.getTitle() + " to playlist!");

        playlistSongs[playlist.size()] = song;

        sectionsPagerAdapter.removeFragment(playlistsFragment, "Playlist");
        sectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PlaylistsFragment(), "Playlist");

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setUpViewPager(viewPager);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    public void removeAll(View view) {
        playlist.clear();
        PlaylistsFragment.songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

```
package sg.edu.tp.musicstream;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private PlaylistsAdapter playlistsAdapter;

    private ListView listView;

    static ArrayList<Song> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);
        

        for (int index =0; index<SongCollection.recommendedSongs.length; index++) {
            
            arrayList.add(SongCollection.recommendedSongs[index]);
        }

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        playlistsAdapter = new PlaylistsAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList, SongCollection.recommendedSongs);

        listView.setAdapter(playlistsAdapter);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                    playlistsAdapter.filter("");
                    listView.clearTextFilter();
                }
                else {
                    playlistsAdapter.filter(s);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id==R.id.settings){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (id==R.id.logOut){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    
}
```

```
package sg.edu.tp.musicstream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class SongCollection
{
    static Song[] recommendedSongs = new Song[14];
    private Song[] playlist1 = new Song[5];
    private Song[] playlist2 = new Song[5];

    public SongCollection()
    {
        //Recommended Songs
        Song photograph = new Song("S1000", "Photograph", "Ed Sheeran","097c7b735ceb410943cbd507a6e1dfda272fd8a8?cid=null",4.32, R.drawable.photograph);
        Song theWayYouLookTonight = new Song("S1001", "The Way You Look Tonight", "Michael Buble","a5b8972e764025020625bbf9c1c2bbb06e394a60?cid=null",4.39,R.drawable.michael_buble_collection);
        Song billieJean = new Song("S1002", "Billie Jean", "Michael Jackson","f504e6b8e037771318656394f532dede4f9bcaea?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965",4.39,R.drawable.billie_jean);
        Song spark = new Song("S1003", "Spark", "TAEYEON","e857ae54599f2cca1703b598cef871664f36e72e?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.63, R.drawable.spark);
        Song darkside = new Song("S1004", "Darkside", "Alan Walker","2acc534ac733f8868c98e13e4f71917fae2e3ce3?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.53, R.drawable.darkside);
        Song diamondHeart = new Song("S1005", "Diamond Heart", "Alan Walker","d75c2b8e870acb087872bd49eeb5d6efb37cfc9d?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.01, R.drawable.diamond_heart);
        Song ocean= new Song("S1006", "Ocean (feat. Khalid)", "Martin Garrix","5ce5ed5600e96f1604aff6b05c0dc35319023a1c?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.61, R.drawable.ocean);
        Song numb = new Song("S1007", "Numb", "Linkin Park","e6ccf7717f8a167bfea4afc1bf7da1a0cd707fbb?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.09, R.drawable.numb);
        Song sadForever = new Song("S1008", "Sad Forever", "Lauv","1250fb3bea03aee6da908ea67420ddd954ad812a?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.39, R.drawable.sad_forever);
        Song kyokiranbu = new Song("S1009", "Kyokiranbu", "GARNiDELiA","ec373ab20f18e1a4a7b19b3abaac3ce605690abd?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.32, R.drawable.kyokiranbu);
        Song gokurakuJoudo= new Song("S1010", "Gokuraku Joudo", "GARNiDELiA","8924599ac778ebfbac7ddc2e5cc87961f82f736c?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.65, R.drawable.gokuraku_joudo);
        Song connect = new Song("S1011", "Connect", "ClariS","6692db454109aa077ed25e65df82a06d34017da6?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 4.5, R.drawable.connect);
        Song wannabe = new Song("S1012", "WANNABE", "ITZY", "2bae7f42bbae3cd75228d6400e37515b79467928?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.19, R.drawable.wannabe);
        Song icy = new Song("S1013", "ICY", "ITZY", "118a0dea24f229f51ffff23a9d334cf5714dbaf6?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965", 3.19, R.drawable.icy);

        recommendedSongs[0] = photograph;
        recommendedSongs[1] = theWayYouLookTonight;
        recommendedSongs[2] = billieJean;
        recommendedSongs[3] = spark;
        recommendedSongs[4] = darkside;
        recommendedSongs[5] = diamondHeart;
        recommendedSongs[6] = ocean;
        recommendedSongs[7] = numb;
        recommendedSongs[8] = sadForever;
        recommendedSongs[9] = kyokiranbu;
        recommendedSongs[10] = gokurakuJoudo;
        recommendedSongs[11] = connect;
        recommendedSongs[12] = wannabe;
        recommendedSongs[13] = icy;

 


    }
```

Comment: did you try to debug your application?
also sharing error stack could be helpful

Comment: I'm so sorry but no. I'm new to android studio... and I'm not sure how to debug. Let me try to share the error.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code. It is really easy. To the left of the code, where the line numbers are, you can click to set a breakpoint. Then, when you run your application by clicking the little bug-icon instead of the play-icon, the app stops where you set the breakpoint and you can see the values of all variables etc. You can then continue the execution line by line and track down your problem easily.

Comment: Ok, I will try and debug. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter, you have three different ways of storing the songs:

> ```
> Song[] songs;
> List<Song> songlist;
> ArrayList<Song> arrayList;
> ```

This is a problem. Pick one type, and use it everywhere.

The adapter is building its logic around the `getCount()` method:

> ```
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return songlist.size();
> }
> ```

Which uses `songlist`. But your `onClick()` method uses `songs`:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v) {
>     for (int index = 0; index < songs.length; index++)
>     // ...
> }
> ```

If you change this to use `songlist` instead, probably the issue will go away.